# WCF Config to fix The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting a error

> The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded

I know I need to modify my WCF configuration but I can't get it working.  Here's what I have so far:  I tried to use the buil-in WCF editor.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <remove contract="IMetadataExchange" name="sb" />
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpRelayBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
        name="sb" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="SvcLibrary.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/SvcLibrary/Service1/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SvcLibrary.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCB is correct the regarding the bindings which again are:

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

But I was also getting the error "The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded" because I needed to modify the client app as follows:

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXRMService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

**The default maxStringContentLength was set to 8192**  I increased it to 65536 and the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your binding section as follows:

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Your endpoint specifies that it is using the wsHttpBinding but you have only configured the basicHttpBinding.

This means that your service will only be using the defaults

By the way those values you have specified are huge, you might want to review those

-- Update

Added a maxReceivedMessageSize attribute to the binding.

Also can you confirm if you have made any changes on the client side. Basically both the client and the server configurations should match.

Comment: I made this change but I still get the same error.  Do I need to edit the endpoint section as well?

Comment: Did you remove the name on the binding so its the same as above?

Comment: Looks like this now: <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the right property (`maxStringContentLength`) but on the wrong binding. The problem is that you're defining the configuration for `basicHttpBinding` but using `wsHttpBinding` on your service endpoint. Change your binding configuration to `wsHttpBinding` and it should work fine (you might want to verify whether you need the WS-* capabilities offered through `wsHttpBinding`, you could also change your endpoint's binding to `basicHttpBinding` and that would work too, as long as you don't need support for distributed transactions, etc.)

Comment: Still getting " The maximum string content length quota (8192) "